# PTR record only visible on two public name servers

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, isp

I submitted a request to an ISP (CableOne) to have a PTR record created..

```
160.2.202.58 mail.huntleylaw.com
```

I've queried 30+ Public DNS servers and I've only been able to find the PTR record on two...

```
ns1.cableone.net (24.116.0.206)
ns2.cableone.net (24.119.5.34)
```

It's been well over the maximum 72 hour time frame they suggest for DNS "propagation"

**My Question:** What might cause a PTR record to only be query-able on two public name servers even after 5+ days?

Answer (score 3):

If that is the address you requested, there is a general problem with the DNS setup.

This lists the DNS servers for `2.160.in-addr.arpa`, which are needed

```
$ host -vra 2.160.in-addr.arpa
...
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
2.160.in-addr.arpa.     86355   IN      NS      ekns03.kodak.com.
2.160.in-addr.arpa.     86355   IN      NS      ekns01.kodak.com.
2.160.in-addr.arpa.     86355   IN      NS      ns.kodak.com.
2.160.in-addr.arpa.     86355   IN      NS      ekns02.kodak.com.
```

All of there servers refuse to answer `58.202.2.160.in-addr.arpa`.

```
Host 2.160.in-addr.arpa not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

The cableone DNS servers answer this query because they consider themselves authoritative for the query. But a query starting at the root will go the the kodak DNS servers, and they don't answer.

You should get your ISP to have this fixed, this is a problem that doesn't just affect you, it affects many more addresses.

Comment: Where did you get this? A `dig +trace` clearly shows delegation to ARIN, then Cableone. No Kodak in the picture...

Comment: This is indeed the wrong test to do. `-a` in host does an ANY query and this is never a good thing to do. You should prefer `dig` in all cases and: 1) always explicitely specify the nameserver you query and 2) do not use ANY but specify the type you need, like PTR here.

Answer (score 1):

The delegation is OK:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +trace 58.202.2.160.in-addr.arpa. PTR @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
.           250233  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           250233  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20180827050000 20180814040000 41656 . YfBKjqc3DFDsvpVOPh8IFmjm5BvTPWdkk20E68uV8a8o6FvrugBz0UQW s5rnoxAD6e9FF2dj2rdnaoiB2PSs+kbpE7vc/pDdIBXBZWK6/OK4e162 ShpifcyGOHMMKIXyNpiIJZNeBrQ89JnHc3jWmmO/n4RJCj2301CYb0Ar bHU/j+Jn8JZMoMf8YTYp+gzZpfIOye3QSbciE6vZEZVDVT+WPIkYTADI ImkXnjqA5TQHRTkw4vJrvk+izfuV8UEYRJtUM3M/8MnV/XZl6UPk2O7i fmZfzv6ukEcq79oACSt8usYZdK1SPCAK3sLC2LB1yzMKDhHHjE6DKw63 whZSJA==
;; Received 525 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) in 28 ms

in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  e.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  d.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  b.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  f.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  c.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  DS  53696 8 2 13E5501C56B20394DA921B51412D48B7089C5EB6957A7C58553C4D4D 424F04DF
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  DS  63982 8 2 AAF4FB5D213EF25AE44679032EBE3514C487D7ABD99D7F5FEC3383D0 30733C73
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  DS  47054 8 2 5CAFCCEC201D1933B4C9F6A9C8F51E51F3B39979058AC21B8DF1B1F2 81CBC6F2
in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20180828000000 20180814230000 4288 arpa. t0YDTKWUUwgd24O9cgqao8XhcOIXc8NbZIXqO0fIsNcPmmr3ibFxlTm9 UuyWev5N48pvOetvyNKyeLNN15uonFlKGP85nVBHwXPix4QemrxJycvC dWbC7zRS5Xa43ijBH0FLS31zfGk4+1wSiXKoBimN/eMS8nxVqDLJSS+J q90=
;; Received 738 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(c.root-servers.net) in 64 ms

160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  u.arin.net.
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  z.arin.net.
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  x.arin.net.
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  y.arin.net.
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  arin.authdns.ripe.net.
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  r.arin.net.
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  DS  3741 5 1 A09067FD4FDD105898FD199345D5625D2B50192F
160.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 3 86400 20180822062001 20180731211721 60309 in-addr.arpa. eQ0yZZ9dF8EnDbyBPAhSGpTCJKZ8bqJEHWbqQO2Pbh74uCSofEf1ntW1 9fbL7ikT7xzVFTlIjig/fcLdm7dpHD+pcKV8M13TluItE1DI9+/JSAOb 0hpfqMu0fXYwixboamrsx6w0xeLVJ5cH/LOiG2Pa0KV2bOxbNx4UELl/ N1M=
;; Received 382 bytes from 203.119.86.101#53(e.in-addr-servers.arpa) in 249 ms

2.160.in-addr.arpa. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.cableone.net.
2.160.in-addr.arpa. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.cableone.net.
2.160.in-addr.arpa. 10800   IN  NSEC    10.20.160.in-addr.arpa. NS RRSIG NSEC
2.160.in-addr.arpa. 10800   IN  RRSIG   NSEC 5 4 10800 20180829003712 20180814233712 29727 160.in-addr.arpa. iv2a5MiEhiLYZtWjvFShYCcX8a3pc4aWrUaI8xTtrdNOHrQRaJMmzPPG klTfm3N4PNnbDrUt1b08Y1s6FS6bO/kmXiO/e0t41120Nnedf7l1UsgP gJ1aScHZoDL231fFZU98aRYx8L3HCgQzvYd7Zj3gSC/ycg/fnK25K09H mig=
;; Received 322 bytes from 204.61.216.50#53(u.arin.net) in 55 ms

58.202.2.160.in-addr.arpa. 43200 IN PTR mail.huntleylaw.com.
2.160.in-addr.arpa. 43200   IN  NS  ns2.cableone.net.
2.160.in-addr.arpa. 43200   IN  NS  ns1.cableone.net.
;; Received 167 bytes from 24.119.5.34#53(ns2.cableone.net) in 90 ms
```

All the 6 authoritative nameservers on `160.in-addr.arpa` (5 ARIN + 1 RIPE) delegate `2.160.in-addr.arpa.` to `ns1.cableone.net` and `ns2.cableone.net`.

How did you do your queries? Quad9 (`9.9.9.9`) replies the same, as do CloudFlare (`1.1.1.1`).

You will need to show more about what you did: what specific commands did you use, and their results.